# How to pass one function result to another function in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have function to create inside of it; I am checking if it's created or not by calling another helper function, but I'm unable to return that helper function result; if I did I can get only as undefined.

Here is my function :

```
//controller / form.js;
exports.createFormsElement = (req, res) => {
  console.log("Post a Elements: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  formById = formsHelper.formById("1");
  console.log("formById" + formById);
  res.send({ result: formById ? formById : "empty" });
  return;
};

//helper/forms.js 
module.exports = {
    formById: function(idForms) {
        Forms.findOne({
            where: {
                idForms: idForms
            },
            attributes: ['idForms']
        }).then(data => {
            return data;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share sample code what you have done?

Comment: //controller/form.js

exports.createFormsElement = (req, res) => {
 console.log('Post a Elements: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
 formById = formsHelper.formById('1');
 console.log('formById' + formById);
 res.send({ result : formById ? formById : 'empty' });return
};
//helper/forms.js
module.exports = {
    formById: function (idForms) {
        Forms.findOne({
            where: { idForms: idForms },
            attributes: ['idForms']
        }).then( data => {
            return data;
         });
    }}

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you have an async operation i.e a database call. Within your function you are expecting a synchronous return from that which dosen't work well as you need to wait for I/O to finish. A solution would be to

```
//controller / form.js;
exports.createFormsElement = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Post a Elements: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  const formById = await formsHelper.formById("1");
  console.log("formById" + formById);
  res.send({ result: formById ? formById : "empty" });
};

//helper/forms.js 
module.exports = {
    formById: function(idForms) {
        return Forms.findOne({
            where: {
                idForms: idForms
            },
            attributes: ['idForms']
        })
    }
}
```

note that there is changes in both helper/forms.js and controller/form.js async is however supported on later versions of node 7.6 or higher natively or you might have to use a transpiler or callbacks.

Comment: Glad it worked , if you think that this is the answer or solution to your question I would appreciate you mark it as correct answer.This also helps a person with similar problem to identify the answer to their problem relatively quickly :)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
function fOne () {
  return 'test'; // "return" passes the function result to the calling function
}

function fTwo() {
  console.log(fOne());
}
```

Comment: I can get this kind of result but if I try to access database I can get but I cant pass it to controller